# Oracle Linux postfix conf SMTP - Default sender 'from' issue

Tags: linux, email, postfix, smtp, mailx

**How do I specify a default sender 'from:' address in postfix config for emails through smtp?**

I'm trying to send emails through SMTP and a relay from two different servers with Oracle Linux 8

The problem is that on one server when you send an email without the '-r' option to specify a sender it doesn't work returning the following message:

```
A Sender: field is required with multiple addresses in From: field.
No such file or directory
"/root/dead.letter" 1/6
. . . message not sent.
```

On the other server, sending an email like this works properly and it sends an email as root@server.postfixcnfspecifieddomain.com

I'll attach consoles of the attempts on both servers:

***Sending Email without -r Option in Server 1***

```
Linux server 5.4.17-2102.201.3.el8uek.x86_64 #2 SMP Fri Apr 23 09:05:57 PDT 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

NAME="Oracle Linux Server"
VERSION="8.4"
ID="ol"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VARIANT="Server"
VARIANT_ID="server"
VERSION_ID="8.4"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
PRETTY_NAME="Oracle Linux Server 8.4"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:oracle:linux:8:4:server"
HOME_URL="https://linux.oracle.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.oracle.com/"

ORACLE_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Oracle Linux 8"
ORACLE_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=8.4
ORACLE_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Oracle Linux"
ORACLE_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION=8.4

[root@server1 ~]# mailx -s "SMTP" user@company.com
test.
.
EOT
A Sender: field is required with multiple addresses in From: field.
No such file or directory
"/root/dead.letter" 1/6
. . . message not sent.
[root@server1 ~]#
```

***Sending email without -r  in Server 2***

```
Linux server 5.4.17-2102.201.3.el8uek.x86_64 #2 SMP Fri Apr 23 09:05:57 PDT 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

NAME="Oracle Linux Server"
VERSION="8.4"
ID="ol"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VARIANT="Server"
VARIANT_ID="server"
VERSION_ID="8.4"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
PRETTY_NAME="Oracle Linux Server 8.4"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:oracle:linux:8:4:server"
HOME_URL="https://linux.oracle.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.oracle.com/"

ORACLE_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Oracle Linux 8"
ORACLE_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=8.4
ORACLE_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Oracle Linux"
ORACLE_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION=8.4

[root@server2 ~]# mailx -s "SMTP" user@company.com
test
.
EOT
[root@server2 ~]#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There are many versions of the `mail` program, including [GNU mailutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/mailutils/) and [bsd-mailx](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/mail/).

   As `mail` on server2 seems to work correctly, make sure that server1 has the same version as server2.
2. Use `/usr/sbin/sendmail` instead of `mail` to send your message.  You're using `postfix` on both machines, and postfix's `sendmail` command understands both `-r` and `-f` options to set the sender address.  See `man postfix` for details and more options.

Comment: I was able to use /usr/sbin/sendmail user@company.com to send an email

With that command you have to remove the -s option for SMTP thank you.